# how to change connection string entity framework in runtime

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, app-config

how to change connection string entity framework in runtime

code in my appconfig file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RelationAtOfficeEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=RelationAtOffice;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

I want to change the following code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="RelationAtOfficeEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=127.10.10.23,1356;Initial Catalog=RelationAtOffice;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

just data source changed.

How is it done?

Comment: what aim do you want ot achieve?

Comment: i wwant change data source in runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiates your context it has parameter connectionString. You can change it there.

Comment: i wwant change data source in runtime for always save to app.config